# magento mutiple shipping address not displaying on front end

Tags: magento

I am working on an existing magento project. Previous development team used custom design. I have enabled multiple shipping address from admin side, and cleared all cache. But am not able to see multiple address option in checkout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have custom design, if the previous development team didn't override the default magento theme, you can switch to it from `System > Configuration > General > Design` 
If they have written their changes directly into the default theme, then you can just rename the base/default (from design and skin) into something like custom/default and copy/paste the base/default from a Magento archive matching your version.

This way you can see if shipping to multiple addresses works or not. If it works then it means it was removed from the custom design - you have to check the design/skin files.

If it doesn't work then either you didn't configure something, or the code was overriden you have to check files under app/code/local (code/community or worse case code/core) .